# Eclipse and Web Project import, run on Server missing!

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, project

I've recently installed STS 2.5.1RELEASE and wanted to import an SVN project in order to continue the development proccess... But I can't manage to get it running on my Tomcat v6 server! This is what I've done:

- Imported the project from SVN (OK)
- Added new server: Tomcat v6.0 (OK)
- Modified Project Facets, so I now have ticked: Dynamic Web Module (2.5) and Java (1.5) with the Apache Tomcat v6.0 runtime selected.

So, when I choose "Run on Server..." and add the project resource to the server, it starts Tomcat perfectly, but my app is never loaded!!

The rare thing is that, in my previous version of STS, I had "Java 5" as a Project Facet instead of Java 1.x... Maybe this is a problem... Any idea??? How can I add the "Java 5" facet?? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the project to the Server?

Comment: When you say it starts Tomcat perfectly do mean that the logs are clean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check project `Properties` -> `Targeted runtimes`. Maybe an incorrect value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue was in the project properties.

Make sure you are not able to see the Server properties. To make them accesible, so you can use "run as", you have to access from the Project properties (right click over the project), the Project Facets and select the Dynamic Web Module.

In my case, after adding it everything worked fine. It added to my build path (project properties/java build path/libraries) the web app libraries